# Where is the link to my privileges page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, privileges

Am I so myopic as to not see the obvious link somewhere? I came looking for it immediately after seeing King Atwood's post but couldn't find it.

It seems appropriate to just put the list on the "reputation" tab of user profile, or at least a prominent link.

Comment: I think a tab on the user profile or a prominent link underneath a users reputation would do the trick.

Comment: but it would be shomehow strange to click it on another users profile and get your own data. `\reputation` could be *added* to the reputation score on the top line of each page (after user name) and `\privileges` eventually as a new link on that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good ideas!

I've linked `/privileges` on

1. <s>your user page, where your actual reputation score is (click it)</s> (now obsolete)
2. <s>the header of every page, where your name is (hover over the name or click the arrow to the left and choose "privileges" from the box)</s>
3. [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
4. The Achievements drop-down menu

Comment: Salute! Works like a charm.

Comment: @Saul - I second that... maybe some text is in order, or direct link under the reputation score?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Was the link removed again? I can't find link to privileges page anywhere on my profile.

Comment: Found it.  In the box when you hover your username at the top of the page.

Comment: Why was the privileges page link from the reputation section of the user profile removed?

Comment: No longer in the topbar (at least not in the same place). Anyone know where it is now?

Answer (score 4):

[`/privileges`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges)

Comment: I know the URL, but I'm asking for a link to click (or just show it on rep tab, as I suggested). And my English tutor needs to spank me for misspelling "privileges" 2 times.

Comment: @Geoffrey, it seems to be by design that some features just aren't linked to. Other examples include timeline edit view, /reputation and direct comment links.

Comment: Why not? Are they supposed to be Easter eggs? What's the URL for "timeline edit view"? `/reputation` can probably stay the way it is.

Comment: @Geoffrey `posts/<questionid>/timeline`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think that this link should go into the official FAQ and replace the table at the end of the "What is reputation?" section.  It seems to be a natural fit there, and would make the official FAQ a little shorter (and being a little shorter means that a few more people will read the whole thing).

For example:

> Amass enough reputation points and Stack Overflow will allow you to [go beyond simply asking and answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).  [End of section]

Even if the team feels that the abbreviated rep table should stay where it is, that would still be an ideal place to put a link to the privileges wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) [sript](http://simu.wikidot.com/local--files/links:links/so_links.user.js) for adding these links to Stackoverflow. The script can be found [here](http://simu.wikidot.com/links:links#toc4) (last link before the "Goodies" section)

[image: Sample]

<sup>My first script, at least I can't remember writing anything in Javascript... so this probably is not the correct or best way to do it...</sup>

EDIT: it would be nice to have at least the reputation and the privileges links integrated in Stackoverflow so they work everywhere, without needing Greasemonkey...

Comment: This is nice, although I think the people who we most want to see the privileges page are precisely the ones who would never in a million years bother with a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: I agree (it's what I tried to say when I edited the answer). Probably it's also kind of an overkill to have the privileges on the top (every page)... but I wanted to play with Greasemonkey :-)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are outdated, the Privileges link from the recent UIs are:

The *Privileges* page from your *Edit Profile & Settings* under the *OTHER* section.

In other way, by URL `https://<sitename>/users/edit/current` then under *OTHER* section.

> [image]

another way, from the top bar when click the *Recent achievements* icon, there is a dialog popup will appear. In the popup the link for the *privileges* page is available.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you moving the images in all my answers to imgur, but can you please preserve the alt description? In some cases it seems like you pulled it into a separate sentence; in other cases it's just gone entirely. Thanks