# Link to the permissions break-down page?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the link to my privileges page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page)

Hmm, it would seem that there's no link on the main interface to the permissions break-down page.  The only way I know of getting to it, is going to a thread and editing it.  Then clicking on the link in the message regarding peer-reviewed edits (since I don't have enough Rep to make a straight edit.)

Perhaps it should be a link when viewing your own reputation?

Comment: Yeah, I just asked about duplicates in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one. Hover over your username and click the privileges link.

[image]

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks.  Have a free 25 rep.