# achievements: goals when you can do more

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the link to my privileges page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page)

On Stack Overflow it isn't possible to see, as far as I know, how many percent you got of your current "rank" and when you will get extra points or when you can perform new tasks.

Is it possible to add a list to display how many points you need in order to reach your next "goal"? And what you can do by then?

Comment: You want - http://stackoverflow.com/privileges - which is linked to from the reputation summary drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps looking for the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges)?

There are a [few ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page) to get to it.

Comment: Sounds fair to me, but I don't see like when you get extra points for free. (I received 100 points after reaching 200 points if I'm not wrong)

Comment: Are you also looking for the reputation audit on your profile? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/197458/robuust?tab=reputation

Comment: @Robuust 100 points you're talking about are most likely due to [meta-tag:bonus-reputation] feature