# Privileges link AWOL?

Tags: discussion, privileges, top-bar

Can't find the Privileges link any more.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67830/135956) is no longer valid.

Can someone please tell me where it's hiding now?

Comment: Help -> View a full list of privileges you can earn ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges )

Comment: It actually had a week of leave left. "Use it or lose it"

Comment: This isn't a dupe of the linked question, which is a vague feature request and not a question about where the privilege link is. It might, however, be a dupe of this general top bar guide: [New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to <X> gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Privileges are still linked from the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

I updated Jeff's answer to cross out the top bar and leave help center as the only remaining location.

Comment: By any chance could it be made a magic link?  Like \[help/on-topic\] becomes [help/on-topic] and goes to .../help/ontopic also work for [help/privileges]?

Comment: Thanks. This raises another question... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210032/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-invalid-answers-after-the-update

Comment: @MichaelT I personally have no objections to that, but it'd need its own feature request.