# What to do with questions which have invalid answers after the update?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I was going to use, as an example, [this question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67830/135956) about where the privileges link lives. Since I've just mentioned it in another question, Anna Lear has edited it to be correct.

The question still remains though...

Should we be deleting them (and re-asking as required), (possibly radically) editing someone else's answer or provide new, correct, answers which will be less visible than existing, possibly accepted ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on meta management is that trying to keep up with everything is likely to be a losing battle, but we should clean up where we can as things come up.

So with that in mind, just editing the answers is typically fine. Certainly preferable to reasking (why have two copies of the same question now, except one is wrong?), and *usually* preferable to re-answering (if a feature request was declined but then implemented, I prefer to post a new answer to cover that instead of editing the decline reason, for example).

Some questions touch on fully obsolete or removed features, and those question can be closed, but I wouldn't go hunting for them.