# Wher are popular questions from old top bar gone?

Tags: support, top-bar

I used to procrastinate on SE by reading recent popular question, which were available from top bar. I can't find them any more. Where are they now?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone