# How do I logout from the new Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, login, logout

I tried to click on my use picture (up bar), but a menu was not opened as it used to be.

How can I logout from the new Stack Overflow site?

Comment: The Stack Exchange drop-down on the left.

Comment: You can find these sorts of thing at  [New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to <X> gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone)