# Where is the Votes panel?

Tags: discussion, votes-tab

Before the panel was visible how many votes I used pure per day 
near avatar.

Tell me where it went and how it can cause. Votes may limit removed? Previously, it was 40.

Comment: On your profile page, at the bottom (under Summary tab)

Comment: And votes limit isn't removed, more like you might not have understood the limit rules before clearly, so have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes

Answer (score 0):

To view your vote totals for the day, week and month, [go to your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) and scroll down to bottom, where you will see the "Votes Cast" box in the right-hand column.

This shows the information that you're after. For a breakdown of all other changes since the new top bar was rolled out, please see [New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to  gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210186/229699).