# "privileges" links on child metas should point to the main site's /help/privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, privileges, per-site-meta

[As of a couple months back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone/210187#210187), a link to /help/privileges can be found on [your profile page](/users/current):

[image: profile page privileges]

This is a problem for child meta sites, since privileges there are (mostly) inherited from the main site. As a result, [the privileges page is empty](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Navigating to [most help center articles](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/help/) on a child meta will *redirect* you to the main site - even [the What is Meta? topic](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) lives on main!

The privileges page should work the same way.

#### Related: [Meta privilege pages blank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214878/meta-privilege-pages-blank)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have made the change - child metas will link directly to the parent site privileges page.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.3.5.1422, meta rev 2014.3.5.2016).

Comment: Did this get reverted somehow? See: [Is there a reason the site-local Meta privileges page is blank?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/is-there-a-reason-the-site-local-meta-privileges-page-is-blank)

Comment: No, nothing changed there - specifically, the "privileges" link on the child meta profile page still points to the parent site privileges page. The issue is that going _directly_ to the page doesn't cause a redirect.