# Are there any guidelines for promoting Stack Exchanges?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, site-promotion

I go to a university where there are plenty of people interested in the topics covered by a lot of Stack Exchanges. However, I couldn't find any guidance on people interested in promoting either the entire Stack Exchange network or a particular site on the network (such as Stack Overflow or one of the beta sites such as Unix and Linux or Theoretical Computer Science).

Are there any specific suggestions, advice, or "dos and do nots" for people wishing to promote the SE Network or a particular Stack Exchange? I'm especially looking for promotional material that can be used when talking to other people (some kind of handout type thing) or that can be posted in a particular area (a flyer). If nothing exists, perhaps a template can be made that can be then applied to every Stack Exchange site as it leaves Beta, so people can then print them and post or distribute them appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these guidelines from Robert:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

We've discussed creating some kind of video as well but we don't have anything yet.

[Explaining Stack Exchange to non-programmers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54533/explaining-stack-exchange-to-non-programmers/54659#54659)

Comment: Fantastic. I'm going to accept this, but it would be kind of cool to see more tips and tricks that people have used to promote their sites.